# Moving the Gallery view to the next image on one swipe in Android?

Tags: android, image, gallery, swipe

I have four images in the Gallery View. When we do swipe from left to right or right to left the Gallery View moves all the images i.e if I swipe from left to right from the first image then it will move to all the four images.

What I want is that when I swipe it should only move to the next image. Can someone let me know how is this possible?

Hope to get a reply soon.

Regards
Sunil

Comment: Did you have to extend the base gallery? If so can you post the onFling override you wrote?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311854/how-can-i-limit-fling-in-android-gallery-to-just-one-item-per-fling

Answer (score 4):

I accomplished this by creating a `CustomGallery` class that extends `Gallery`. I then Overrode the `onFling` method of `Gallery`. Inside the `onFling` method, simply return false. This will cause the Gallery to only move to the next image when `onFling` is called.

Comment: The downside of this is that it doesn't feel smooth - when flinging, the animation is there but the photo returns back to the current photo instead of going next one.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this without using a Gallery: put an ImageView on your Layout and detect Swipes using [GestureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection). On Left or right swipe, cycle through the imageList in appropriate direction and set the image in the ImageView. When you set the image, play appropriate slide left or slide right animation.

Comment: I found manipulating the default behavior of Gallery widget non-trivial; this is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

use a `ViewFlipper` concept with fling concept ... try using this comment

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
{ 
    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > 50) 
         return false; 

    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 10 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 10) 
    { 
         vf.showNext();
    }  
    else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 10 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 10) 
    { 
         vf.showPrevious();
    } 

    return false; 
}
```