# how to disable fling in android gallery

Tags: android, gallery, onfling

I have a custom gallery in my app and after doing some testing I've decided that I don't want the gallery to navigate with finger swipes.  I've set up a left and right button to control it instead.  Now I want to figure out how to disable the `onFling` method.  I've tried `this.setEnabled(false);` which didn't work, and tried `this.setClickable(false);` which didn't work... also my overridden `onFling()` method has everything except the return(true); commented out.... not sure what else to try!  Any ideas??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

A better approach (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311854/how-can-i-limit-fling-in-android-gallery-to-just-one-item-per-fling)) is to override the fling method in your custom gallery class:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                       float velocityY) {        
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh, got it!

In my custom gallery class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;

}
```

Figured that put from the gallery source code posted here:
http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java.shtml

:)

Comment: This is simply disables any user input!