# How to stop flinging on Gallery in Android without extending Gallery class

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery, onfling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable fling in android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426439/how-to-disable-fling-in-android-gallery)

I have an Activity class with a **Gallery** widget and some more widgets. That class extends `Activity`. Now I want to stop ***fling*** attribute which is in Gallery.

Is there any Listener interface or something like that which I can get help to stop *Flinging* of the Gallery when I need.

Comment: repeated question , check the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/4311854/582571

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426439/how-to-disable-fling-in-android-gallery

Comment: simply override onFling method for your gallery view and return false

Comment: @AndroidCoader this question is not repeated. I have done my home work before posting this question. If I have to override `onFling` method I have to extend Gallery class.

Comment: do u want only the fling to be stopped?

Comment: do u want to stop touch on this gallery ?

Comment: @AndroidCoader no not the touch. I want to handle Fling attribute at a certain point of the Gallery. Getting the "certain point" part has completed. Only handling Fling is remaining

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this without overwriting the gallery, but this will also stop all other onTouch Events.

Put your Gallery inside a RelativeLayout and create another View that lies over the whole gallery view as a transparent layer.

You now need to overwrite the [onInterceptTouch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventHandlers) method of this View and return true.
Now all touch events should be intercepted in your view and the gallery will not get any touch events that it can use to start a fling.