# Moving the Gallery view to the next image on one swipe in Android?

Tags: android

I have four images in the Gallery View. When we do swipe from left to right or right to left the Gallery View moves all the images i.e if I swipe from left to right from the first image then it will move to all the four images.
What I want is that when I swipe it should only move to the next image. Can someone let me know how is this possible in galleryview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311854/how-can-i-limit-fling-in-android-gallery-to-just-one-item-per-fling

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to work with gesture for change the images with finger swipe.For that below code may helpful for u.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class GesturesActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.spells);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
}

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    // We want at least one prediction
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
        // We want at least some confidence in the result
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            // Show the spell
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a ViewFlipper with Gestures on it, look at this example:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html

EDIT:

Oh, obviously you should implement the gesture detection, take at look at this question/answer

[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Comment: cant we control that in <Gallery</Gallery> (XML File)

Comment: it's easier to use this approach imo, overriding the standard gallery behaviour could be tedious

Comment: i added back and next button in this activity if i press the left button and right  corresponding image i need to show.i can get image name how to pass that in gallery adapter

Comment: are you using the gallery or the viewflipper? first case: just do -> pos = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition(); gallery.setSelection(pos+1); - second case -> viewFlipper.showNext();