# Gallery - lock swipe gesture to advance only one item at a time in the adapter?

Tags: android

Is there a way to customize Gallery such that one swipe gesture only advances the gallery by a single item?

For example, I have 5 items in my Gallery. When I swipe, it scrolls the content as fast as possible, and I usually hit the end of the gallery with a single swipe. Ideally a swipe of any force would only advance to the next item in the adapter.

I could possibly use ViewSwitcher to do this instead, seems like Gallery is 90% of the way there for me though,

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you don't do that. Your users are accustomed to the way swiping works. If you change it, they're going to feel your application is slug is, strange or both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311854/how-can-i-limit-fling-in-android-gallery-to-just-one-item-per-fling

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem. Here's how I solved it:

Create a custom Gallery that extends Gallery:

```
public class CustomGallery extends Gallery {


    public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context,attrSet);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
return false
}
```

Then in your xml layout make a gallery widget that uses this custom gallery:

```
<com.CustomGallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then in your main activity call that custom gallery as follows:

```
public class mainactivity extends Activity{


    private CustomGallery myGallery;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

        myGallery = (CustomGallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

...
```

This worked for me, although there are issues with it, as you may or may not discover, depending on your implementation...Good luck.